# Was Thanos's life also at stake when the snap happened?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

When the historical snap happened, half of the population of the universe turned into ashes and faded away in the air.

So my question is, did he know that he'll survive the snap and there was no risk to his life or was there?

How can he be so sure that he'll survive the snap?

Afterall he lives in the same universe.

Comment: He knew and accepted that he might be among the ones that would disappear, he brought that up during the discussion of why he is doing it, so he could have just as easily disappeared but happened not to.

Comment: @GµårÐïåñ Where/when did he discuss that? With whom?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir When they are on his home planet and he is describing how it went from being great to not, etc...just queue it up and have at it.

Comment: @GµårÐïåñ I've just rewatched that bit, there no mention of what you said.

Comment: I know for a fact that the concept of sacrifice for the greater good without bias or judgement, anyone can go even me, was discussed, but I may have the wrong scene in my mind and it wasn't on Titan with DS, but I distinctly remember him bring this up during the movie. I will try and find some time to watch it again and try to jot down some time markers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### I don't think so. No.

In a conversation with Dr. Strange on Titan when they first met he said:

> **Dr. Strange:** Who wants to murder trillions.
>   **Thanos:** With all six stones, I could simply snap my fingers. They would all cease to exist. I call that mercy.
>   **Dr. Strange:** And then what?
>   **Thanos:** I'd finally rest and watch the sun rise on a grateful universe.

His last line implies that he will be there when all this happens, so he is spared from the snap.

**Additional notes:**

- The way he executed the snap also implies that he should live. I mean he was there surrounded by the avengers. If he allowed himself to be included, he would risk letting the gauntlet with all the infinity stones just lying there for the avengers to use to revert back. I think the biggest task in his plan is ensuring that no one will tamper with it, so he must live to do that (I guess this might be the plot of the next Avengers movie).
- He is the last person from Titan, so he is spared whether he intended to or not as per his plan of taking only half of the population of each planet.

Comment: Good catch. However, the user GµårÐïåñ says in a comment that Thanos discussed in another part of the movie that he himself might die. I'd like to read that quote too....

Comment: @BrettFromLA I've just read his comment. I have no recollection of that discussion. Perhaps asking GµårÐïåñ about it would be better.

Comment: Rest also implies that he could be dead, as in at rest. So that doesn't mean expected to be alive, but either way he would be done and hopefully the world is grateful for his actions. Dead or alive is not made specific.

Comment: @GµårÐïåñ Ok, I'll give you "rest", but how about "watching the sunrise"? You can't do that if you are dead, can you?

Comment: So this implies he somehow knew that he'd survive the snap when talking with Dr Strange. Maybe, just maybe when he put all 6 stones in the gauntlet, something happened in his body and that could've made the snap exclude him.

I also read in other question that after the snap before disappearing, he had this expression of surprise on his face for a few seconds.

Comment: @RJ He has the stones and he controls the gauntlet so he can exclude/include whoever he wants. I've added some additinal notes.

Comment: Watching the sunrise is a metaphor for starting over and continuing on. Sort of like the world will continue on. That again implies nothing about the person being there, unless we feel that the universe revolves around us, tomorrow we are not here, the universe will continue on and the sun will continue to rise.

Comment: Before reading the additional notes I would say that the phrase "I'd finally rest and watch the sun rise on a grateful universe" is a poetic way of saying "Either I die or not, I will rest in peace". However the additional notes are pretty convincing.